# Axios - Associative Array in params

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I currently have an associative array

```
let filter = []
filter['parent_id'] = 1
```

my axios code

```
const request = await axios.get(`${api.url}`, {
            ...config,
            paramsSerializer: {
                filter                
            }
        });
```

but it's did not make output as what i expected.

in the url it should be `url?filter['parent_id']=1`

is there any idea how to do this?

Thank You

SOLVED

```
let filter = []
filter['parent_id'] = ''
filter['country'] = 'indonesia'
const params = {}
Object.keys(filter).map((item,index) => {
  console.log(item, index)
  const key = `filter[${item}]`
  Object.assign(params, {[key]: filter[item]})
})
console.log(params)
```

Comment: You want to pass filter['parent_id'] or do you want to set filter['parent_id'] = 1? Or do you want to pass a parameter that has the value 1?

Comment: i want the param gonna be filter['parent_id'] = 1, if there is another key in the filter variable, i want the param gonna be filter['key1'] = value&filter['key2']=value etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issues, with looping the keys of the arrays, and create the params, look below for the code

```
let filter = []
filter['parent_id'] = ''
filter['country'] = 'indonesia'
const params = {}
Object.keys(filter).map((item,index) => {
  console.log(item, index)
  const key = `filter[${item}]`
  Object.assign(params, {[key]: filter[item]})
})
console.log(params)
```

Answer (score 0):

So as I understood you want to send each value of the array as a parameter with a GET request. The easiest way is to create a string you can attach to the url.

```
//your array *side note, let will only be available in block scope not global, not sure which scope you have to use filter, just keep that in mind, ill use var just to be as general as possible. You can change this!
var filter = []
var my_get_params = "";
for(var key in filter) {
  let this_value = filter[key]
  if(my_get_params.length > 0)  {
   //we are at the beginning, we use ? instead of & to concat params
  my_get_params+= "?filter_"+key+"="+this_value;
  } else {
   //we are at the beginning, we use ? instead of & to concat params
   my_get_params+= "&filter_"+key+"="+this_value;
  }
}
```

Now `my_get_params` will look like: `?filter_0=myvalue&filter_1=myvalue2`....

Let's add it to the request:

```
    axios.get('/your_request_url'+my_get_params)
    .then( (response) => {
        //console.log("response", response.data);
        return response.data;
    })
    .catch( (error) => {
        //console.log(error);
        return error;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
axios.get(
    'URL', 
    {
        params: {
            param_name: multidimensional_associative_array
        },
        paramsSerializer: function (params) {
            return $.param(params)
        },
    }
);
```

This is my solution using jQuery, the doc shows how to do it with npm QS: https://axios-http.com/es/docs/req_config